# what does ubuntu use instead of /etc/users

Tags: users

I am working on setting up a Ubuntu system for a class project.
I am trying to show how to check for existing users.
My ubuntu has no `/etc/users`.
Waht does it use instead of `/etc/users`?

Comment: I've never heard of a system that has `/etc/users`; where did you see it?

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/passwd`, which is the file that all Unix distributions use.

Answer (score 2):

Regardleslly of how/where the users accounts are stored, you can view them with

```
getent passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

/etc/passwd

You can use `cat /etc/passwd` to view its contents.